# how to include Modernizr - page broken

Tags: jquery, html, modernizr

I have some templates for a site. Mainly, formed with  tags. On the other hand, I need to add an animation, and I was going to follow a tutorial. The tutorial recommends to include modernizr with detection for all CSS3 features, htmlshiv, and touch events.

I included modernizr on the head of my document, also added class="no-js" on the html tag and obviously, jquery is included.

But it does make the page completely blank.

I am reading the documentation for Modernizr and I don't think it is clear at all or on a basic level, and I can't understand why it makes my page blank!!

So if I am using  should I do something else a part from including Modernizr to be able to use them?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us the build of Modernizr you are using? With no code or MCVE it is impossible to diagnose what could possibly go wrong with your document. What troubleshooting steps have you tried, such as incrementally adding resources back to a barebones document? At which step does your page fail?

Answer (score 0):

Well, never mind, it is solved.

The issue was I am using bootstrap for the grid system and they crash with each other. Modernizr adds a hidden class to all the html, so I just needed to excluded it from Modernizr.